# Fluentd daemonset alternative to S3 on Azure (Blob)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-blob-storage, devops, fluentd

For log-intensive microservices, I was hoping to persist my logs into blobs and save them in azure blob storage (s3 alternative). However, I noticed that fluentd does not seem to support it out of the box.

Is there any alternative for persisting my logs in azure like so in S3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plugins that support Fluend with Azure blob storage,specifically blob append:

```
  Azure Storage Append Blob output plugin buffers logs in local file and uploads them to Azure Storage Append Blob periodically.
```

there's a step by step guide available [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/fluent-plugin-azure-storage-append-blob) which is a Microsoft solution, there's also an external plugin with same capabilities [here](https://github.com/htgc/fluent-plugin-azurestorage)

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy solution to use a lightweight log forwarding agent from DataDog which is called vector. This is, of course, free to use and a better alternative to fluentd for a non-enterprise level use case.

I recently set that up to forward the logs from Azure AKS to a storage bucket in near real-time. Feel free to check out my [Blog](https://medium.com/@piyush.sachdeva055/streaming-aks-kubernetes-logs-to-azure-blob-storage-using-vector-a-step-by-step-guide-e3044aa92d57) and Youtube [Video](https://youtu.be/wG-lcsKa9Lc) on the same. I hope it helps.